# vuejs mouseover add class to this element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I add class on mouse over on list item & remove class on mouse leave

```
<li class="test" @mouseenter="thumbStyle" @mouseleave="thumbStyle2">1</li>
<li class="test" @mouseenter="thumbStyle" @mouseleave="thumbStyle2">2</li>
<li class="test" @mouseenter="thumbStyle" @mouseleave="thumbStyle2">3</li>
```

In data & methods

```
data(){
  isActive:false
}

thumbStyle:function(){
   this.isActive = true;
},


thumbStyle2:function(){
   this.isActive = false;
},
```

I have tried this but it is only adding class to first element (li) when I over on any list(li). So what is the technique to add only `this`(hovered) `li`. Like in jquery there are `$(this)`

Comment: Whats wrong with `:hover`? Also can you show an example of your actual code, as if the li elements are static HTML and not a model then toggling state is not going to happen

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In actual code there are static HTML. 10 `<li>` there

Comment: Put it in a model like in my answer below, or use jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved as belows

```
thumbStyle:function(e){
            var clickedElement = e.target;
            $(clickedElement).addClass('active');
        },
        thumbStyle2:function(e){
            var clickedElement = e.target;
            $(clickedElement).removeClass('active');
        },
```

Comment: You should not use jQuery and vuejs at the same time. You'll have 2 frameworks changing the same DOM object that can lead to an inconsistent state on the vuejs state. You should take advantage of the reactive features of vuejs.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to handle this is that each of the elements you want to control the state of, are a model, then you can easily manipulate the state of each item.

Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [{
        label: 'Planes',
        active: false
      }, {
        label: 'Trains',
        active: false
      }, {
        label: 'Automobiles',
        active: false
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" 
      @mouseenter="item.active = true"
      @mouseleave="item.active = false"
     >{{ item.label }} is {{ item.active }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there many list so define like `active: false` for each item is tedious. However I have solve it by jquery

Comment: Yeah sure, though you could in the `beforeMount()` method loop over the data and attach a prop to it so you dont need to define it from get go, in vue everything should really be in a model or another component especially if it changes or is a **list**..